# Ajax beforeSend function doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form to send a small textfile to the server where it's data is processed with **PHP**. The result is shown in a colorbox. It works fine, but i want to show a small message to my user while his data is being uploaded and processed (which takes couple of seconds) and hide it again after the result is shown. But that message `(span#ajaxloading)` doesn't appear for some reason.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="fixit">Fix it!</button><span id="ajaxloading" style="display:none;">Your data is being processed...</span>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery("#fixit").click(function() {
    if(form.valid() == true ) {
        var formData = new FormData(jQuery('#ajastaja')[0]);
        jQuery.ajax({
            beforeSend: function(){
                jQuery('#ajaxloading').show(); // <- Not working!
            },
            url: '/path/to/my.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery('#ajaxloading').hide(); // <- Works here
                jQuery('#answerbox').html(data);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        jQuery.colorbox({
            inline:true,
            href:'#answerbox',
            width:'500px',
            closeButton:false
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

When i remove the "display:none" rule it shows of course and hides after the color box pops up (like it should). So what i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

edit: I'm sorry for the confusion, **the code is actually wrapped** between jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... }); - it just contains a lot of JQuery Validation plugin methods, rules etc which shouldn't affect the issue i have.

Comment: dode you missed the colen at the end your functin }) change this to });

Comment: @Yaseen dode there is no need for `semi-colon` in `jquery`, its optional not compulsory.

Comment: @Yaseen No need for colon ';' untill it is compressed.

Comment: If `show();` not working how `.hide();` is working ? how did you check this ?

Comment: can you please try with $.ajax instead of jQuer.ajax.

Comment: Rishi, i just removed the "display:none" rule. Harsh Sanghani, i can't - it's WP and jQuery is in a safe mode.

Answer (score 5):

try deleting the following line

```
async: false,
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

If beforeSend function is not working try calling your click function this way..

Jquery:

```
    jQuery("#fixit").click(function () {
    jQuery('#ajaxloading').show();
    if (form.valid() == true) {
        var formData = new FormData(jQuery('#ajastaja')[0]);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/my.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery('#ajaxloading').hide(); // <- Works here
                jQuery('#answerbox').html(data);
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
                jQuery('#ajaxloading').hide();
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        jQuery.colorbox({
            inline: true,
            href: '#answerbox',
            width: '500px',
            closeButton: false
        });
        return false;
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#ajaxloading').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found your code was fine, form wasn't defined in the snippet, but beforeSend is working here:

[Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/45zoZD)

Like the other answers I had to wrap it in a document.ready, but that may have already been done outside your snippet?

```
    var formData = new FormData(jQuery('#ajastaja')[0]);
    jQuery.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(){
          console.log('beforeSend')
            jQuery('#ajaxloading').show(); // <- Not working!
        },
        url: '/path/to/my.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery('#ajaxloading').hide(); // <- Works here
            jQuery('#answerbox').html(data);
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
```

Comment: Yes, it is, sorry for the confusion. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your click function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fixit").click(function() {
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's actually already wrapped. I edited my post.